# how to add horizontal scroll bar to mat-chip

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-components, horizontal-scrolling

here is my code in home.component.html

```
<div class="scrollmenu" >
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let category of categories" class="matchip">
    {{ category.cat_name }}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</div>
```

below you can see home.component.css

```
.scrollmenu{
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
  white-space: wrap;
}
.matchip {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but this is not working.I need to show my mat-chips list horizontally scrollable. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to override the css of the internal wrapper class `mat-chip-list-wrapper` to get the horizontal scroll working:

```
::ng-deep .mat-chip-list-wrapper {
  flex-wrap: unset !important;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

You can checkout the working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxyvf9?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Thank you very much.You save me.This is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in home.component.css

```
.matchip{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I hope this is what you are looking for

```
.scrollmenu{
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.scrollmenu ::ng-deep .mat-chip-list-wrapper{
  flex-wrap: inherit !important;
}
```